# Convention for a matching Unicode code point while respecting the BOM?

Tags: c++, c, string, unicode

When searching for a codepoint in a Unicode string with a relevant BOM (UTF-16/32), it makes sense to leave the encoding as-is and match the codepoint to the string's BOM.

For example, I want to trim leading and trailing slash characters.

(pseudocode)

```
utf16 trim_slash(utf16 string) {
   bom = bom_from_strong(string)
   utf16_slash = utf16_byte_order("/", bom)

   offset = 0

   search codepoint from right
      if codepoint[i] = utf16_slash
         offset++

   if offset
      string = string.substr(0, len(string) - offset)
}
```

For doing the same with preceding codepoints, I would skip over the BOM and in the case I want to extract a substring, I would simply add the BOM back on.

I'm using ConvertUTF.cpp from LLVM for UTF operations which seems to respect the BOM when converting between encodings but I still need to take the byte order into consideration when comparing with string literals and strings from other sources.

Am I going about this the right way and is my effort justified? I want to ensure that I have as proper handling of Unicode as I can.

I'm currently standardized on converting all incoming strings to UTF-32 where I need to walk along codepoints to compare search terms and then extract some substring. But I see that this is overkill when I only need to walk along the beginning and the end of a string such as the example pseudocode. In this case it would be much faster to just return the same string if nothing changes; whereas with UTF-32 I have to convert to UTF-32 and then back to the original width and then pass the final copy as the result.

With UTF-32 the minimum is 3 copies per call versus one copy if I were to consider the BOM.

Additionally, converting between UTF formats may result in a string which does not align to the original representation (having BOM or not, regardless or endianess).

Comment: Avoid relying on BOMs but require an explicit encoding info or require UTF-8 (the most common Unicode encoding) straight away. Also, when reading bytes, first normalize them to an internal representation, like UTF-32 or UTF-8, both of course in their native byte order. Similarly, when writing, create the byte-order you want in the file only in the last step. Internally, avoid using multiple different representations of text.

Comment: The whole reason for this post on handling BOM comes from the Unicode standard recommending that a BOM not be removed when it's there, so that round-tripping between encodings does not lose information, and so that code that relies on it continues to work.

Comment: The conceptual problem here is that the BOM is a "once per document" thing, not "once per string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, BOMs are only relevant "on-the-wire" meaning that they signal the byte order of a file, network data, or some other protocol stream as it is transmitted between systems (see [the Unicode FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom2)).

When such a stream is read by a program (e.g. when your `utf16 string` is created), it should be converted to the platform's native byte order. That is, `string` should always in the native byte order and the BOM becomes irrelevant. When the `string` is written back to a file/network/stream, it should be converted from the native byte order into whatever is appropriate for the protocol (with a BOM).

Code that works with strings (other than reading/writing byte streams) should never need to handle non-native byte orders.

Comment: The question is seeking answers for handling situations where the BOM is relevant.

Comment: My answer says that the BOM should never be relevant in the situations described by your question.

Comment: Typically the only situation a BOM should be relevant in, should be the encode/decode layer converting the on-disc/network byte representation to internal strings. Trying to operate directly on the encoded form of a string seems like a lot of pain and not something you'd want to do unless there was some particularly compelling and unusual reason.